# How to unset complex type property (store it as null) in nuxeo?

Tags: nuxeo

I have a complex type, for example, a user type with  such structure:
username: string,
name: string

But when I don't set the value, it stores as map with empty fields 'username' and 'name'
How to change this behaviour in Nuxeo, I just want to see the null value, if it wasn't set

I tried to add attributes nillable in schema description, but it didn't help